# Construct a list of all the integers in a list l which are greater than a given value v in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I would expect

input : `maxNumbers 5 [1,4,5,6,8,4,5,8]`

output : `[6,8,8]`

**My Approach:**

```
maxNumbers ::a =>[a] -> [a]
maxNumbers n (x:xs) = enumFrom(n < x) + maxNumbers n xs
```

Comment: `g v xs = [x | x <- xs, x ..... v]`. means, "list of each x in xs, such that `x ..... v` holds".  What should `.....` be? ---- in your code, you probably meant `maxnums n (x:xs) = [x | n < x] ++ maxnums v xs`. Will any list always match the pattern `(x:xs)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is lacking in your signature is a way to tell haskell that the elements in your list can be ordered (the `Ord` typeclass). This is not true for every type so you have to take that into account.

```haskell
maxNumbers :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
maxNumbers x = filter (>x)
```

Is an implementation that should work.

Comment: thanks peri4n. That worked. But where do you specify on the 2 input arguments i.e. 1> variable 2> list . eg 5 [2,3,4,5]

Comment: @CosmicBadal `filter` is only partially applied, and so has the desired type. This is just a simpler way of writing `maxNumbers x xs = filter (>x) xs`.

Comment: One could go completely point-free and write `maxNumbers = filter . flip (>)` (ew) or `maxNumbers = filter . (<=)`, but answer strikes a sweet spot between brevity and readability.

Comment: @chepner Wow thank you. Can you explain the first line of the code. i.e. maxNumbers :: Ord a => a => [a] -> [a]. I got the last [a] is the returning list.

Comment: The `a` is the threshold below which you want to remove items; the first `[a]` is the list you are filtering. Since `maxNumbers :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, then `maxNumbers x :: [a] -> [a]`, the same as `filter (> x)`.